# Retry to webservice happening automatically in retrofit 1.6.1

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, retrofit, retrofit2

Iam using retrofit 1.6.1 as restclient wrapper to my rest api.

If i send a request to a webservice and if the webservice gives response anything other than 200 OK my code automatically retries 7 times within a span of 1 second.

Below is the code snippet.

```
    public interface Client 
    {
        @POST("/message/messageId")
        Response postMessages(@Path("messageId") String messageId, @Body SomeObject object);
    }

    **Initialization of retrofit using rest adapter is as follows**

    private void Config() {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://someurl.com")
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
    }

    public <T> T getService(final Class<T> iFace) {
        return restAdapter.create(iFace);
    }
```

I will be calling the postMessages API in my business logic class where i just check for response 200 OK and nothing else and end my logic there.

If I get anyother response other than 200 OK 7 retries to the webservice URL are happening every 1 second. Why is this?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you actually make the call? It's the first time I hear about this issue.

Comment: private Response processmessages(final String msg) {
  final MessageDefinition definition = this.gson.fromJson(msg, MessageDefinition.class);
  _LOG.info(" Message is sent to the backend");
  return this.Client.postMessages(definition);
 }

Comment: Th retrofit is retrying to call the webservice 7 times for every 1 second interval.How do i avoid it